# How many ways to distribute 10 peoples into three house? Check my answer.

Tags: combinatorics

There are three houses named A, B, C. Every house can accommodate 3 or 4 people. How many ways to distribute 10 peoples into A, B, and C?

I try to answer as below:

I divide into 3 cases:

- House A accomodate 3 people, house B accomodate 3 people, house C accomodate 4 people
- House A accomodate 4 people, house B accomodate 3 people, house C accomodate 3 people
- House A accomodate 3 people, house B accomodate 4 people, house C accomodate 4 people

So, we have
$$10 C{3}\cdot 7C3\cdot 4C4+10C4\cdot 6C3\cdot 3C3+10 C{3}\cdot 7C4\cdot 3C3=12600.$$

Is it right answer? Please correct if wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You answer is correct but perhaps an easier way to solve (or at least visualize) is the following:

Clearly one house will have $4$ people and the other two will have $3$ each.  Pick $4$ people to be in the crowded house, then $3$ to be in the next house (where "next" means the next letter in the alphabet, with C wrapping back to A).  Finally you have $3$ ways to pick the crowded house:

$$3 \times {10 \choose 4} \times {6 \choose 3} = 3 \times 210 \times 20 = 12600$$